# How do I model the data in json format in c#?

Tags: json, deserialization

Given the following data in json format.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-10-20T17:46:13",
    "data":
        [ // this is essentially a dictionary
           {"Pressure": 0.11},
           {"Temp A": 47.88},
           {"Temp B": 46.69}
        ]
}
```

Is it correct to model in c#

```
public class PayloadModel
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public PayloadData Data { get; set; }
}

public class PayloadData
{
    public Dictionary<string, float> Data { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class PayloadModel
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, float>> PayloadData { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to deserialize into a c# class.

```
PayloadModel pm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayloadModel>(payload);
```

What's the correct way of modeling in c#?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to fix a PayLoadModel class if you want to use your code

```
PayloadModel pm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayloadModel>(payload);

public class PayloadModel
{
   [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, float>> PayloadData { get; set; }
}
```

But I recommend to use a Dictionary instead of a List of Dictionary

```
var jsonParsed =JObject.Parse(json);

PayloadModel pm = jsonParsed.ToObject<PayloadModel>();

pm.PayloadData= ((JArray) jsonParsed["data"])
.ToDictionary(p => ((JObject) p).Properties().First().Name,
              p =>(float)  ((JObject) p).Properties().First().Value);

public class PayloadModel
{
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    
    public Dictionary<string, float> PayloadData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted as the solution. However, I had to remove the declarative attribute [JsonProperty("data")] from public Dictionary<string, float> PayloadData { get; set; } in PayloadModel?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted as the solution. However, I had to remove the declarative attribute [JsonProperty("data")] from public Dictionary<string, float> PayloadData { get; set; } in PayloadModel to avoid an error when calling  ```PayloadModel pm = jsonParsed.ToObject<PayloadModel>();
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Single]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.